# Use range filter for django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to filter the objects with id. like this below.

fetch more than 12 , between 6 and 12, something like this..

I set `RangeFilter()` like this but it shows only equal.
not more than, less than

```
class MyTextFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    my_text = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    id = filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','myText')
```

---

Thanks to @Mohammad Ali answer

I alter the code like this ,but still
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'` error.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
class MyTextFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    my_text = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
    id = filters.CharFilter(method='id_filter')
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','myText')

def id_filter(self, queryset, value, *args, **kwargs):
    return queryset.filter(id>int(value))
```

---

Finally I solve the problem with this.

```
    return queryset.filter(id__gte=args[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter method for each fields in your filter class.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as df_rest_filter

class MyTextFilter(df_rest_filter.FilterSet):
    id = df_rest_filter.CharFilter(method='idFilter')

    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id')

    def idFilter(self, queryset, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value > 12:
             return queryset.filter(id=value)
        else:
             return queryset
```

Comment: Thank it gaves me a great hint!! I think almost I am there,but I want to give the `12` as variable, could you see my altered article and help?

Comment: Can you explain more? You want to give 12 as variable from where. It come from your frontend?

Comment: I solved the problem, I updated the article how I done. What I want to do is getting the input variable from `args[0]`. thanks for your help.